# Get Faulty Route in Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, spring-camel

When using camel, I can use

```
onException(Excepction.class).process(new ExceptionListener())
```

to react to exceptions on routes. Within my ExceptionListener I can get the exception, but is there a way to find out **where exactly** the exception was thrown?

I want to destinguish multiple error sources programmatically, so I can react differently to a servicecall error for service *xyz*, servicecall for *abc* and a bean call. I know I could just wrap every service call in a try-catch-block, but I would have to do this a lot and my route would end up quite chunky.

Answer (score 0):

The doc says:

> When Camel error handler handles an error such as Dead Letter Channel
> or using Exception Clause with handled=true, then Camel will decorate
> the Exchange with the route id where the error occurred.

So you can get the id of the involved route via:

```
String failedRouteId = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.FAILURE_ROUTE_ID, String.class);
```